# context of view page doesn't show reaction block

Tags: views, 7

So, I'm trying to have a block show up when my page has a specific page view, and to do so I use the context module.

To make sure my context works, I added a class to the html. It does show up.

But, when i add a block reaction, the desired block never shows up.

However when I use path as a context it does. Problem is, path doesn't cut it for me.

So what do I need to do to get my block to display when the context is a view page.